# Kafka Group coordinator 10.*.*.*:9092 (id: 2768927897 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery. Getting this error in consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

Consumer is throwing this error continuously and rebalancing every 5-10 seconds.

> Group coordinator 10.*.*.*:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery.

I have tried all possible ways to sort or this error but not able to solve it.
I can delete the kakfa logs and do it but that is not the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

**Increase your maximum CPU core usage**

I've been having this problem in our production environment. Here's how I retrace and fixed it.

I use java spring here, hope it helps

- We have a consumer group which consume 9 different topics with 10 partition each. **No problem at all** for years. Until there is development that adds 2 more topics and then here is the problem persist.
- Our application also handles REST API which looks up the consumed data that we stored in our Database.
- The weird thing is, we tested it back in dev environment and have no problem at all even though the load is way more than the production during loadtesting.
- We noticed there's difference in cpu core limits between dev and prod and apparently the application is using a lot of cores. So, we tested it in dev with ridiculously low cpu core limit and *voila* the error comes.
- We finally increase the core usage limit in production and then the problem doesn't come again.

In short, the consumer is taking cpu core way more than we anticipated. The consumer failure happened due to the lack of cpu cores when the application tried to open a new consumer.

What I don't understand about this issue is, why does KafkaListener in java-spring isn't throwing OOM error instead of killing the consumer when there is not enough CPU core for opening a new consumer. This way it maybe could lessen the confusion.